Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $H \approx \overline{H}$. It is "correct" to say $\overline{H}$ is a subgroup of $G$?
This question in the title is motivated by the following problem:

Find a subgroup of $S_4 \oplus S_4$ that has order 4 but is not of the form $K \oplus L$ where $K$ and $L$ are subgroups of $S_4$.

The best idea I have for this problem is the following: Let $K = \langle (1\,2\,3\,4) \rangle$ and $L = \langle (1) \rangle$. This way, we can say that $K \oplus L < S_4 \oplus S_4$ is a subgroup of order 4, as both $K < S_4$ and $L < S_4$ implies this. Although our subgroup is in an unwanted form, observe that $K \approx \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $L \approx \mathbb{Z}_1$ so that $K \oplus L \approx \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_1 \approx \mathbb{Z}_4$.
But from here, is it correct to say that $\mathbb{Z}_4 < S_4 \oplus S_4$? It seems odd to say, as we are dealing with isomorphism rather than some "direct" equivalence, and part of me doubts the person who wrote this question intended for this as an answer. This leads to the more general question posed in the title.

I don't understand your point. The subgroup you're talking about is of the form $K\oplus L$.

@TedShifrin I mean to "morph" the subgroup of the form $K \oplus L$ into a form that is not that, namely $\mathbb{Z}_4$, in order to satisfy what this question wants.

In this problem, the appearance of the phrase "of the form" does not give you leeway to replace the subgroup $\langle (1234) \rangle \oplus \langle(1)\rangle$ by something that subgroup is not set-theoretically equal to.

What do you mean by "$(1)$"?

@Kan't The cycle structure that maps $1 \to 1$. This would be the identity permutation, which I could have also be denoted $(1,2)$.

Not really, the identity permutation is usually denoted with either $()$ or $(1)(2)(3)(4)$. Btw, $(12)$ swaps 1 and 2.

@Kan't My mistake (too late to edit now)! I meant to write $(1,2)(1,2)$, that's the way it's commonly written in the textbook I'm following.

Thank you for all of your answers. I'm answering my own question here to provide my interpretion of this question and why my initial notion was incorrect, mostly motivated by @LeeFischer's comment.
In general, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is isomorphic to a group $\overline{H}$, we can't say that $\overline{H}$ is necessarily a subgroup of $G$. If we could say this, then $\overline{H}$ is a subset of $G$—meaning every element in $\overline{H}$ is an element of $G$—which is not guaranteed.
A great example of this is the example provided in the question. We can't say that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is a subgroup of $S_4 \oplus S_4$, because clearly $S_4 \oplus S_4$ contains no element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (is $1 \in S_4 \oplus S_4$?). Even though there is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and a subgroup of $S_4 \oplus S_4$, namely $K \oplus L$, and even though there is a notion of similarity between the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and this subgroup as a consequence of this isomorphism, the set $S_4 \oplus S_4$ contains elements only from that subgroup, not $\mathbb{Z}_4$. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ cannot be a subgroup.
As for finding a subgroup that satisfies the condition posed in the question, I have not found one yet. I will edit this answer and mention it once I do.


Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $H \approx \overline{H}$. It is "correct" to say $\overline{H}$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Not strictly, no.
This is evident in any infinite group $G$ that has a proper $H< G$ isomorphic to $G$ itself. To say "$G$ is a subgroup of $G$" alone loses information, since $K\le K$ for all groups $K$.

The question is not asking you about an isomorphism, but about actual subgroups of $S_4 \oplus S_4$ that don't have a direct sum decomposition inherited from the direct sum decomposition of $S_4 \oplus S_4$.  So your example is not an example, because it is $K \oplus L$ where $K$ and $L$ are subgroups of $S_4$.
Consider $C_p \times C_p$ where $C_p = \langle g\rangle$ is cyclic of prime order $p$. Inside this group, let $H = \langle (g,g)\rangle$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $C_p \times C_p$ and it is not $K \times L$ where $K$ and $L$ are subgroups of $C_p$: if $H = K \times L$ then $p = |H| = |K||L|$, so $K$ or $L$ is trivial and the other has order $p$. That's impossible since it would imply $H \subset C_p \times \{1\}$ if $L$ is trivial or $H \subset \{1\} \times C_p$ if $K$ is trivial, but that would mean all elements of $H$ have trivial 1st coordinate or trivial 2nd coordinate, which is wrong because $(g,g)$ is in $H$ and neither coordinate is trivial (in fact the only element of $H$ with either coordinate being trivial is its identity element).
